# htaccess, if the image is not found go to other location

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess rule that is not working now.

```
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^store/images/products/p(\d+)/cache/([^.]+).card.jpg
    RewriteRule  ^$ index.php?r=backend/product/imageNew/$1/$2 [R,L]
```

The rule should force the broken images like this one: /store/images/products/p6/cache/imagine.card.jpg to enter on this rule.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule will never fire due to conflicting regex pattern matches.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^store/images/products/p(\d+)/cache/([^.]+)\.card\.jpg$ index.php?r=backend/product/imageNew/$1/$2 [R,L]
```

You're matching `^$` in `RewriteRule` but matching URI = `store/...` in `RewriteCond`.